# Magento 2 - Best approach to display and customize Recently Viewed Products with slider

Tags: magento2, product, widget

Using our custom theme, we need to display `Recently Viewed Products` block on product detail page. We followed below approach

- Under Admin Panel we have `Content -> Widgets`
- Add Widget -> choose widget type `Recently Viewed Products`
- Type = `Recently Viewed Products`
- Design Theme = `Assign my theme`
- Widget Title = `Recently Viewed Products`
- Assign to Store Views = `Select as you need`
- Sort Order = `(Add as per you need) else leave empty, it will set to 0`
- Layout Updates - `Add Layout Update`
- Display on = `All Product Types`
- Products = `All`
- Container = `Main Content Area`
- Template = `View Products Grid Template`
- Under `Widget Options`
- Number of Products to display = `7`

Now, on product detail page, recenlty viewed products in grid form can be seen. How could I achieve below

1. Change title from **Recently Viewed** to **Recently Viewed Products** ? To
   customize, which `template/xml` file I have to extend and modify in
   my custom theme to achieve the same ?
2. For product count more than `5`, the product displays in second row
   as seen in image attached. How could I add a slider so that `5`
   products are seen and if more than 5 then slider will appear ? In Magento 
   1.9 they have a slider code. Add a class="slideshow-container" for a parent 
   container and add class="slideshow" for a ul or ol

[image]